# Merging multiple columns with similar names in one data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a df like this:

```
 id  mon.1  tue.1 wed.1 mon.2  tue.2 wed.2 mon.3  tue.3 wed.3
HD82   1     0     1      1     0      1     1     0      0
HD83   0     0     0      1     1      0     1     0      1
HD84   1     1     0      1     1      0     0     1      0
```

Each `mon/tue/wed` column includes a number of occurrences that have been measured over a number of weeks, but I want to combine the columns in order to have a total for each day, and a data frame that looks like this:

```
id mon tue wed
```

e.g. I want to make a data frame where the columns would be monday = mon.1+mon.2+mon.3, tuesday = tue.1+tue.2+tue.3 etc.

Any ideas how would I do this?

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example ? For instance with dput ?
I'm not sure I understand your request, you want to create a dataframe with day=day.1+day.2+day.3 ?

Comment: please provide some dummy data to work with and to show what you've tried so far (for instance by `dput`ting a bit of your `df`

Comment: are your column names always structured as day.number? i.e., can you extract the bit before the `.` to have the day part?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a read at [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [Minimal, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

your `df` is currently in `wide` format, where each cell (apart from the `id` column) represents one measurement. You can use `tidyr` to transform it to `long` format -where each row in the dataframe represents one measurement, and then easily aggregate over days:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
#some dummydata
df <- data.frame(a.1=c(1:10),
                 a.2 = c(1:10),
                 b.foo = c(1:10),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
#transform to long format
dfLong <- gather(df,"dayWeek","value") %>%
#extract day name
         mutate(day = gsub("\\..*","",dayWeek)) %>%
#summarise
         group_by(day) %>%
         summarise(dayTotal = sum(value))
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to extract the part before the `.`. This can be done with the following function:

```
day_extract<-function(x)
{
  x<-as.character(x)
  strsplit(x, ".", fixed = T)[[1]][1]
}
```

Try to apply this function to you dataframe.